# Could not load type 'IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient'

Tags: c#, asp.net, identitymodel

I try to make a request to an API with methods authorized by an access token from identity server, but when I send a request using a Bearer Token in Header, my request fail and the result marks me this error:

> Could not load type 'IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient' from
>   assembly 'IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=e7877f4675df049f'. at
>   IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions.ConfigureJwtBearer

Comment: Please add some code sample

Comment: did you ever solve the issue ?

Comment: Stuck on the same issue !! exception within the signalR middleware when adding Bearer attribute on my API.

Comment: Update your IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation to Version 3.0 or higher. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/issues/124